# fastcgi - passing information to scripts

Tags: nginx, symfony-1.4, fastcgi

I`m new with nginx and I dont know even what should I look for. My task is to force (I think it is)  **fastcgi** to pass information (**PATH_INFO**) to the scripts. I have been told that I should add something in block after **location ~ .php$** . Adding before **fastcgi_pass xxx;**

```
fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
```

would made that happened ?

My location part config file looks like that:

```
location ~ ^/backend\.php/(.*)$ {
    try_files $uri /backend.php?$1;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    # Zero-day exploit defense.
    # http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,88845,page=3
    # Won't work properly (404 error) if the file is not stored on this server, which is entirely possible with php-fpm/php-fcgi.
    # Comment the 'try_files' line out if you set up php-fpm/php-fcgi on another machine.  And then cross your fingers that you won't get hacked.
    try_files $uri =404;

    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_pass xxx;
}
```